# Which file formats does recording text-to-speech in OS X support?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, recording, text-to-speech

Speech using the `say` command can be recorded like this:

```
say -o hello.aiff 'hello world'
```

What other formats are supported besides `aiff`? I already tried `wav` and `mp3`, and they don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man say`, the supported file formats are

> --file-format=format
>
> The format of the file to write (AIFF, caff, m4af, WAVE). Generally, it's easier to specify a suitable file extension for the output file.

`.wav` doesn't work since it needs to be written as `.wave`. No DOS 8.3 restriction here.

It is also possible to specify the data format. See `man say` for additional information.

Comment: It seems to create a wave file but it won't play in iTunes.

Comment: @Phenom: This is a limitation of iTunes / Mac OS X. I also was unable to create a WAVE file that was playable by Get Info preview/QuickLook, but I could play it just fine using the [Switch Sound File Converter](http://www.nch.com.au/switch/index.html).